# heat map development - color regulation

Tags: heatmap, here-api

I am trying to visualize geo data in a city. I would like to show the density in different colors. Is it possible? I am referring to the picture below. Also I would like to add one heat map in this heat map. The on that fits in can have as the one below only one color. How do I do this?

[city heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeg6h.png)

Here is an out-cut of my code: "*a69=48.1271,11.5397&rad69=1k&l69=3&a70=48.1513,11.5545&rad70=1k&l70=3&a71=48.1811,11.6057&rad71=1k&l71=3
"*

I am happy if someone can help. Regards,

Elisabeth

Answer (score 0):

You specify different colors with the level of heat parameters **l0**, **l1**, **l2**, etc. corresponding with the region and radius.  You can find more in the [API documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/resource-heat.html):

> Level of heat for the area/region. Levels have to be
>   distinguished by indexes when showing multiple areas/regions i.e.l0,
>   l1 etc. The index number is used for linking the level to similarly
>   indexed area/region. When presenting only a single area/region, the
>   index 0 of the parameter is not required i.e. plain l can be used.
>   Currently there are 4 different level values supported: 0, 1, 2 and 3.
>   If not defined for certain index, similarly indexed area/region will
>   use level 0 by default. Levels are represented on map by using
>   following pre-defined colors:
>
> 0 - Blue
>
> 1 - Purple
>
> 2 - Red
>
> 3 - Yellow

Using the [heatmap example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/examples-heatmap.html) from the docs and your parameters you are setting each to yellow.  You can also change the opacity and color palette with additional parameters.

For example:

```
curl -X GET -H 'Content-Type: *' --get 'https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/heat' --data-urlencode 'app_id=APP_ID_HERE' --data-urlencode 'app_code=APP_CODE_HERE' --data-urlencode 'a0=48.1271,11.5397' --data-urlencode 'rad0=1k' --data-urlencode 'l0=3' --data-urlencode 'a1=48.1513,11.5545' --data-urlencode 'rad1=1k' --data-urlencode 'l1=2' --data-urlencode 'a2=48.1811,11.6057' --data-urlencode 'rad2=1k' --data-urlencode 'l2=1'
```

Gives the following result:

[image: heatmap example]